# Как сделать IPIP туннель Linux-Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, ipip

Есть два сервера, в разных ЦОД на windows и linux. Требуется "телепортировать" свободный IP с linux на сервер с Windows. 
По описанию это IPIP, но никак не могу найти описания как это сделать в формате Linux-Windows.

Comment: Я точно знаю, что такая реализация была на WIndows Server 2000, в составе "сервера маршрутизации и удаленного доступа" . Однако в поздних версиях я её не встречал. Может проще виртуальную unux-машину поднять внутри Win-сервера или развернуть какой-нибудь VPN-сервер на одной из сторон (OpenVPN,mpd5,ipsec, etc.)?

Comment: @Daemon-5 мне пришлось именно так и поступить, использую OpenVPN. Но он слишком медленный, и пакеты через него ходят с ощутимой задержкой.

Comment: Мне кажется, туннель с IKEv2 должен быть вполне вменяемым решением, особенно если понизить шифрование .

Comment: ike2 тут будет сложен в настройке. l2tp+proxyarp самое то